# Self-study: why does the MLE cause selection bias when select subset of variables from large-scale predictors?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, feature-selection, large-data, high-dimensional

In the paper [“TWEEDIE’S FORMULA AND SELECTION BIAS”](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/BIO%20256.pdf) the author Bradley Efron said the MLE can cause selection bias, which confuses me a lot.

> We suppose that the statistician observes some large number of estimates $z_i$, each with its own unobserved expectation parameter $\mu_i$. The largest few of the $z_i$'s are likely to substantially overestimate their corresponding $\mu_i$'s, this being an example of *selection bias*, or regression to the mean."

Could anyone tell me why the MLE can cause selection bias when select subset of variables from large-scale predictors?